# .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Incorrect syntax near 'f'

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'm trying to run the following query, where the `id` is the primary key. The `F` from `425F` is underlined red and the following error is shown:

> Incorrect syntax near 'f'.

Does anybody know what's going on?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE id = E9485FD0-0888-425F-B1B6-BC32B4B5045E
```

I don't have the option of declaring it as a varchar variable, although that did fix the error.

Comment: What is the type of the `id` column?

Comment: If the `id` column is a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` use the following literal syntax to search for a GUID value: `WHERE id = {guid'E9485FD0-0888-425F-B1B6-BC32B4B5045E'}`

Comment: You can also enclose the values in single quotes (example: `'E9485FD0-0888-425F-B1B6-BC32B4B5045E'`) and it will be implicitly converted to a GUID type

Comment: try to fully qualify your table

Comment: Missing quote `'`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here:

1. You are using a reserved keyword as the name of your table. SQL Server will allow you to do this, but any time you run a query against this table, you'll need to enclose the table name inside of square brackets like this: `SELECT * FROM [table]`
2. When you perform a comparison operation on a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, you need to enclose it within single quotes like this: `WHERE id = 'E9485FD0-0888-425F-B1B6-BC32B4B5045E'`

So, after applying both of those changes, your query should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE id = 'E9485FD0-0888-425F-B1B6-BC32B4B5045E'
```